# Django + Apache + mod_wsgi = Bad Request (400)

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, bad-request

I'm trying to get my app launched on VPS in `Debug=True` mode.

I'm using Django 1.6 with Python 2.7.

I tried simple wscgi 
script and found that it works well (basically returns 200 and "Hello world" in text/plain) 
to the browser. Here's my configuration:

**virtual host config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.domain.info
ServerAlias www.subdomain.sigizmund.info
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/subdomain/index.wsgi
Alias /static/ /var/www/subdomain/static/
ErrorLog /tmp/subdomain.error.log
CustomLog /tmp/subdomain.custom.log common
LogLevel debug
<Location "/static/">
  Options -Indexes
</Location>
<Directory /home/sgzmd/code/myproject>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**index.wsgi**

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/home/sgzmd/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

PROJECT_PATH = '/home/sgzmd/code/myproject'
if PROJECT_PATH not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_PATH)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import cStringIO

import pprint

class LoggingMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, application):
        self.__application = application

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        errors = environ['wsgi.errors']
        pprint.pprint(('REQUEST', environ), stream=errors)

        def _start_response(status, headers, *args):
            pprint.pprint(('RESPONSE', status, headers), stream=errors)
            return start_response(status, headers, *args)

        return self.__application(environ, _start_response)

application = LoggingMiddleware(django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
```

I have following logging output: http://pastebin.com/SnZVEeT1 (from LoggingMiddleware) and `/var/log/django/error.log` while is being created and re-created, remains completely empty.

I figured that the app is loading, by editing settings.py of my project, which content is available here: http://pastebin.com/Byr8RStb

Would appreciate any pointers and ideas, as I'm basically out of options now.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work for a start:

```
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate_this.py")
```

This is because Apache runs as a special user and ~ will not expand to your own user where virtualenv was setup.

No idea if this is relevant or not though.